# PyQt5 динамическое расположение кнопок

Tags: python, pyqt5

Здравствуйте! Начал изучать PyQt5 и наткнулся на первый тупик. 
Размещать кнопки абсолютным позиционированием нет смысла, так как мое приложение может работать как в полноэкранном режиме, так и в укороченном. Поэтому нужно сделать так, чтобы кнопки сами становились в нижний правый угол, или хоть в какой, мне надо понять сам принцип. В этом собственно и вопрос, как же это сделать? 
Мои попытки были таковы:

```
self.okButton = QPushButton("OK", self)
self.cancelButton = QPushButton("Cancel", self)
hbox = QHBoxLayout()
hbox.addStretch(1)
hbox.addWidget(self.okButton)
hbox.addWidget(self.cancelButton)

vbox = QVBoxLayout()
vbox.addStretch(1)
vbox.addLayout(hbox)

self.setLayout(vbox)
```

Но кнопки просто лежат одна на другой, так что видно только одну, а под ней другая (проверял это, всовывая в код метод move() )

Надеюсь вы сможете найти ошибку в моем коде или подсказать решение. Спасибо!

P.S. При запуске из терминала (я еще и конвертировал скрипт в .exe, но разницы никакой) выдает нечто, понятое мной как "Попытка установить слой на класс Test, который уже является слоем" :

```
$ python main.py
QWidget::setLayout: Attempting to set QLayout "" on Test "", which already 
has a layout
```

Comment: Так надо указывать ячейки, в которые устанавливаешь виджет, нет разве? Так они тебе и сваливаются в одну ячейку. А вообще, если знаешь, что хочешь, но не поймешь, как это выглядеть должно в коде, то проще накидать в Дизайнере и потом глянуть код, а оттуда, если надо, переписать начистоту.

Comment: Пробовал делать в дизайнере, но там только абсолютное позиционирование в пикселях видел. Да, скорее всего не нашел, но с нуба большего не возьмешь...

Comment: Почитай про компоновщики

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QWidget, QPushButton,
    QHBoxLayout, QVBoxLayout, QApplication)


class Example(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        okButton = QPushButton("OK")
        cancelButton = QPushButton("Cancel")

        hbox = QHBoxLayout()
        hbox.addStretch(1)
        hbox.addWidget(okButton)
        hbox.addWidget(cancelButton)

        vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        vbox.addStretch(1)
        vbox.addLayout(hbox)

        self.setLayout(vbox)

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 300, 150)
        self.setWindowTitle('Buttons')
        self.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Правильно написал @ФилиппБондарев, вам надо почитать про компоновщики. Судя по тексту ошибки, вы пытаетесь установить виджету компоновщик повторно.